# append extra parameters to ajax call query string

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append extra parameters to query string for each ajax call

assuming the original url is: `/customer/search?sort=Id`, I want the processed url looks like

```
/customer/search?sort=Id&criteria=abc
```

this is the code

```
   $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        // Append the initial search criteria
        options.url += '&criteria=abc';
   });
```

the problem is: after one click, the url becomes: `/customer/search?sort=Id&criteria=abc`

after second click, the url becomes: `/customer/search?sort=Id&criteria=abc&criteria=abc`

it keeps adding up

It looks like jQuery ajax call is using the same `options` object, so I added a custom flag

```
  $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        // Append the initial search criteria
        if (!options.processed) {
            options.url += '&criteria=abc';
            options.processed = true;
        }
   });
```

the problem is: `options.processed` is always `undefined`. looks like every ajax call is using a unique `options` object. now I am confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you simply do

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
     //check if the new parameter has already ben added
     if(options.url.indexOf('&criteria') === -1){
        options.url += '&criteria=abc';
     }
});
```

Comment: I simplified the question, in real project, the appending part is dynamic, keep changing. so I can not do the `indeoxOf` check. thanks!